# Using row_to_json() with nested joins

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to map the results of a query to JSON using the `row_to_json()` function that was added in PostgreSQL 9.2.

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to represent joined rows as nested objects (1:1 relations)

Here's what I've tried (setup code: tables, sample data, followed by query):

```
-- some test tables to start out with:
create table role_duties (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar
);

create table user_roles (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar,
    description varchar,
    duty_id int, foreign key (duty_id) references role_duties(id)
);

create table users (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar,
    email varchar,
    user_role_id int, foreign key (user_role_id) references user_roles(id)
);

DO $$
DECLARE duty_id int;
DECLARE role_id int;
begin
insert into role_duties (name) values ('Script Execution') returning id into duty_id;
insert into user_roles (name, description, duty_id) values ('admin', 'Administrative duties in the system', duty_id) returning id into role_id;
insert into users (name, email, user_role_id) values ('Dan', 'someemail@gmail.com', role_id);
END$$;
```

The query itself:

```
select row_to_json(row)
from (
    select u.*, ROW(ur.*::user_roles, ROW(d.*::role_duties)) as user_role 
    from users u
    inner join user_roles ur on ur.id = u.user_role_id
    inner join role_duties d on d.id = ur.duty_id
) row;
```

I found if I used `ROW()`, I could separate the resulting fields out into a child object, but it seems limited to a single level. I can't insert more `AS XXX` statements, as I think I should need in this case.

I am afforded column names, because I cast to the appropriate record type, for example with `::user_roles`, in the case of that table's results.

Here's what that query returns:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"Dan",
   "email":"someemail@gmail.com",
   "user_role_id":1,
   "user_role":{
      "f1":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"admin",
         "description":"Administrative duties in the system",
         "duty_id":1
      },
      "f2":{
         "f1":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Script Execution"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What I want to do is generate JSON for joins (again 1:1 is fine) in a way where I can add joins, and have them represented as child objects of the parents they join to, i.e. like the following:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"Dan",
   "email":"someemail@gmail.com",
   "user_role_id":1,
   "user_role":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"admin",
         "description":"Administrative duties in the system",
         "duty_id":1
         "duty":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Script Execution"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's there in the setup code. The inserts. I went to the trouble of setting everything up so anyone could replicate my situation.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Update: In PostgreSQL 9.4 this improves a lot [with the introduction of `to_json`, `json_build_object`, `json_object` and `json_build_array`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html), though it's verbose due to the need to name all the fields explicitly:

```
select
        json_build_object(
                'id', u.id,
                'name', u.name,
                'email', u.email,
                'user_role_id', u.user_role_id,
                'user_role', json_build_object(
                        'id', ur.id,
                        'name', ur.name,
                        'description', ur.description,
                        'duty_id', ur.duty_id,
                        'duty', json_build_object(
                                'id', d.id,
                                'name', d.name
                        )
                )
    )
from users u
inner join user_roles ur on ur.id = u.user_role_id
inner join role_duties d on d.id = ur.duty_id;
```

For older versions, read on.

---

It isn't limited to a single row, it's just a bit painful. You can't alias composite rowtypes using `AS`, so you need to use an aliased subquery expression or CTE to achieve the effect:

```
select row_to_json(row)
from (
    select u.*, urd AS user_role
    from users u
    inner join (
        select ur.*, d
        from user_roles ur
        inner join role_duties d on d.id = ur.duty_id
    ) urd(id,name,description,duty_id,duty) on urd.id = u.user_role_id
) row;
```

produces, via http://jsonprettyprint.com/:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Dan",
  "email": "someemail@gmail.com",
  "user_role_id": 1,
  "user_role": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "admin",
    "description": "Administrative duties in the system",
    "duty_id": 1,
    "duty": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Script Execution"
    }
  }
}
```

You will want to use `array_to_json(array_agg(...))` when you have a 1:many relationship, btw.

The above query should ideally be able to be written as:

```
select row_to_json(
    ROW(u.*, ROW(ur.*, d AS duty) AS user_role)
)
from users u
inner join user_roles ur on ur.id = u.user_role_id
inner join role_duties d on d.id = ur.duty_id;
```

... but PostgreSQL's `ROW` constructor doesn't accept `AS` column aliases. Sadly.

Thankfully, they optimize out the same. Compare the plans:

- The [nested subquery version](http://explain.depesz.com/s/UUU); vs
- The latter [nested `ROW` constructor version](http://explain.depesz.com/s/jxy) with the aliases removed so it executes

Because CTEs are optimisation fences, rephrasing the nested subquery version to use chained CTEs (`WITH` expressions) may not perform as well, and won't result in the same plan. In this case you're kind of stuck with ugly nested subqueries until we get some improvements to `row_to_json` or a way to override the column names in a `ROW` constructor more directly.

---

Anyway, in general, the principle is that where you want to create a json object with columns `a, b, c`, and you wish you could just write the illegal syntax:

```
ROW(a, b, c) AS outername(name1, name2, name3)
```

you can instead use scalar subqueries returning row-typed values:

```
(SELECT x FROM (SELECT a AS name1, b AS name2, c AS name3) x) AS outername
```

Or:

```
(SELECT x FROM (SELECT a, b, c) AS x(name1, name2, name3)) AS outername
```

Additionally, keep in mind that you can compose `json` values without additional quoting, e.g. if you put the output of a `json_agg` within a `row_to_json`, the inner `json_agg` result won't get quoted as a string, it'll be incorporated directly as json.

e.g. in the arbitrary example:

```
SELECT row_to_json(
        (SELECT x FROM (SELECT
                1 AS k1,
                2 AS k2,
                (SELECT json_agg( (SELECT x FROM (SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b) x) )
                 FROM generate_series(1,2) ) AS k3
        ) x),
        true
);
```

the output is:

```
{"k1":1,
 "k2":2,
 "k3":[{"a":1,"b":2}, 
 {"a":1,"b":2}]}
```

Note that the `json_agg` product, `[{"a":1,"b":2}, {"a":1,"b":2}]`, hasn't been escaped again, as `text` would be.

This means you can *compose* json operations to construct rows, you don't always have to create hugely complex PostgreSQL composite types then call `row_to_json` on the output.

Comment: Thanks so much! Would that be roughly the same speed of query as the original, or do you think there is an additional cost to using a subquery?

Comment: @dwerner I would be surprised if the query plans didn't work out much the same, but strongly advise you to `explain analyze` on a more realistic sample of data to see.

Comment: @dwerner Question edited with explain links showing the plans are, in fact, identical.

Comment: If I could upvote your answer a couple more times, I would. I appreciate the detail, and the bit about 1:many relationships.

Comment: @dwerner Glad to help. Thanks for making the effort of writing a good question; I'd like to bump *it* up a few more times too. Sample data, Pg version, expected output, actual output/error; ticks all the boxes, and is clear and easy to understand. So thanks.

Comment: Any downsides to creating a custom type with the desired names and casting to that type (i.e. `row_to_json(row(c1, c2, ...)::type_with_good_names)`) to get around the unpleasant "subquery to get useful property names" stuff? The query in question isn't a one-off but it would be the only thing using the custom type.

Comment: @muistooshort Quite harmless. Just a `pg_type` entry and some more `pg_attribute` entries. I wouldn't want to do so for thousands of queries, mainly because it'd get annoying to maintain, but that's about it.

Comment: @muistooshort: A temp table to provide the type serves, too, and is deleted automatically ate the end of the session.

Comment: Am I correct saying, that [this commit by Tom Lane](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1XnvSy-0005yA-9V@gemulon.postgresql.org) (branches from 9.2 up to HEAD) will solve the issue with column aliases?

Comment: @vyegorov I don't think so; that's just a bugfix, albeit a useful one. It doesn't add support for aliasing records.

Comment: Thank you so much for the 9.4 example. `json_build_object` is going to make my life much easier but somehow I didn't pick up on it when I saw the release notes. Sometimes you just need a concrete example to get you started.

Comment: Super answer - agree that the documentation should highlight `json_build_object` a bit more - it's a real game changer.

Comment: @CraigRinger Would you happen to know where I can read more about `scalar subqueries returning row-typed values`? I know what a scalar subquery is, but I could not find documentation/info. on the part of the query that says": `SELECT x FROM (...) x`

Comment: @dgo.a If `x` is a table, then `SELECT x FROM x LIMIT 1` returns a single row-typed value. It's scalar, in that it returns a single concrete value. But that value is a composite type, a row. You can also use the row constructor to get a `record` result like `SELECT ROW(1,2,3)`

Answer (score 6):

I am adding this solution becasue the accepted response does not contemplate N:N relationships. aka: collections of collections of objects

If you have N:N relationships the clausula `with` it's your friend.
In my example, I would like to build a tree view of the following hierarchy.

```
A Requirement - Has - TestSuites
A Test Suite - Contains - TestCases.
```

The following query represents the joins.

```
SELECT reqId ,r.description as reqDesc ,array_agg(s.id)
            s.id as suiteId , s."Name"  as suiteName,
            tc.id as tcId , tc."Title"  as testCaseTitle

from "Requirement" r 
inner join "Has"  h on r.id = h.requirementid 
inner join "TestSuite" s on s.id  = h.testsuiteid
inner join "Contains" c on c.testsuiteid  = s.id 
inner join "TestCase"  tc on tc.id = c.testcaseid
  GROUP BY r.id, s.id;
```

Since you can not do multiple aggregations, you need to use "WITH".

```
with testcases as (
select  c.testsuiteid,ts."Name" , tc.id, tc."Title"  from "TestSuite" ts
inner join "Contains" c on c.testsuiteid  = ts.id 
inner join "TestCase"  tc on tc.id = c.testcaseid

),                
requirements as (
    select r.id as reqId ,r.description as reqDesc , s.id as suiteId
    from "Requirement" r 
    inner join "Has"  h on r.id = h.requirementid 
    inner join "TestSuite" s on s.id  = h.testsuiteid

    ) 
, suitesJson as (
 select  testcases.testsuiteid,  
       json_agg(
                json_build_object('tc_id', testcases.id,'tc_title', testcases."Title" )
            ) as suiteJson
    from testcases 
    group by testcases.testsuiteid,testcases."Name"
 ),
allSuites as (
    select has.requirementid,
           json_agg(
                json_build_object('ts_id', suitesJson.testsuiteid,'name',s."Name"  , 'test_cases', suitesJson.suiteJson )
            ) as suites
            from suitesJson inner join "TestSuite" s on s.id  = suitesJson.testsuiteid
            inner join "Has" has on has.testsuiteid  = s.id
            group by has.requirementid
),
allRequirements as (
    select json_agg(
            json_build_object('req_id', r.id ,'req_description',r.description , 'test_suites', allSuites.suites )
            ) as suites
            from allSuites inner join "Requirement" r on r.id  = allSuites.requirementid

)
 select * from allRequirements
```

What it does is building the JSON object in small collection of items and aggregating them on each `with` clausules.

Result:

```
[
  {
    "req_id": 1,
    "req_description": "<character varying>",
    "test_suites": [
      {
        "ts_id": 1,
        "name": "TestSuite",
        "test_cases": [
          {
            "tc_id": 1,
            "tc_title": "TestCase"
          },
          {
            "tc_id": 2,
            "tc_title": "TestCase2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ts_id": 2,
        "name": "TestSuite",
        "test_cases": [
          {
            "tc_id": 2,
            "tc_title": "TestCase2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "req_id": 2,
    "req_description": "<character varying> 2 ",
    "test_suites": [
      {
        "ts_id": 2,
        "name": "TestSuite",
        "test_cases": [
          {
            "tc_id": 2,
            "tc_title": "TestCase2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion for maintainability over the long term is to use a VIEW to build the coarse version of your query, and then use a function as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc_query_prominence_users( )
RETURNS json AS $$
DECLARE
    d_result            json;
BEGIN
    SELECT      ARRAY_TO_JSON(
                    ARRAY_AGG(
                        ROW_TO_JSON(
                            CAST(ROW(users.*) AS prominence.users)
                        )
                    )
                )
        INTO    d_result
        FROM    prominence.users;
    RETURN d_result;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY INVOKER;
```

In this case, the object prominence.users is a view.  Since I selected users.*, I will not have to update this function if I need to update the view to include more fields in a user record.

Comment: This stepCAST(ROW(users.*) AS prominence.users) ommit if necessary, enough with table name!