# Join tables using a value inside a JSONB column

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

There are two tables:

Authorized Contacts (`auth_contacts`):

```
(
userid varchar
contacts jsonb
)
```

`contacts` contains an array of contacts with attributes `{contact_id, type}`

`discussion`:

```
(
contact_id varchar
discussion_id varchar
discussion_details jsonb
)
```

The table `auth_contacts` has at least 100k records making it non JSONB type is not appropriate according as it would double or triple the amount of records.

Sample data for `auth_contacts`:

```
userid  | contacts
'11111' | '{"contact": [{"type": "type_a", "contact_id": "1-A-12"}
                      , {"type": "type_b", "contact_id": "1-A-13"}]}'
```

`discussion` table has 5 million odd records.

I want to join on `discussion.contact_id` (relational column) with contact id which a json object inside array of json objects in `auth_contacts.contacts`.

One very crude way is:

```
SELECT *
FROM discussion d 
JOIN (SELECT userid, JSONB_OBJECT_KEYS(a.contacts) AS auth_contact
      FROM auth_contacts a) AS contacts
      ON (d.contact_id = contacts.auth_contact::text)
```

What this does is actually at runtime create (inner sql) userid vs contact id table (Which is what I was  avoiding and hence went for JSONB data type
This query for a user with large records takes 26 + seconds which is not all good.
Tried a few other ways: [PostgreSQL 9.4: Aggregate / Join table on JSON field id inside array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520150/postgresql-9-4-aggregate-join-table-on-json-field-id-inside-array)

But there should be a cleaner and better way which would be as simple as 
JOIN `d.contact_id = contacts -> contact -> contact_id?`
When I try this, it doesn't yield any results.

When searching the net this seems to be a pretty cumbersome task?

Comment: If you try to use `contacts->'contact'->'contact_id'` it will not get any values since `contact` is an array. Technically you could use something like `contacts->'contact'@>'[{"contact_id":"1-A-12"}]'` but for joining based on that I'm not sure it would be that efficient.

Comment: contacts->'contact'->0->'contact_id', contacts->'contact'->1->'contact_id' returns subsequent values.  As for '@>' it is actually for checking condition (whether left contains within right) and cannot be used for join as per my knowledge. Would it be possible ?

Comment: It is possible to do an ugly `SELECT * FROM discussion d JOIN auth a ON a.contacts->'contact'@>('[{"contact_id":"'||d.contact_id||'"}]')::jsonb` based on a quick test, but I wouldn't expect it to be that performant. Maybe using `jsonb_array_elements()´ would be better, but it still has to explode the values out of the JSON anyway.

Comment: Agreed yes. But as you mentioned, performance wise it is a killer. I am thinking there should be a quicker and cleaner way like it is in MongoDB?

Comment: What is a `lakh record`? Your "crude way" is invalid syntax. I am also confused by your cardinalities: 5 MM in `discussion`, how many in `auth_contacts`?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Supported by a matching index, the contains operator should actually perform very well for big tables.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, it would, but in this case my ugly way would generate a jsonb object dynamically for every row and then search for that, I'm pretty sure that will be a huge performance killer, or would it be fast? If it was used with a static jsonb, it would be usable.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: The index is used on the `auth_contacts` side. For instance to look up auth_user for a given discussion. For the other direction, you would unnest an then join utilizing the PK index on `discussion.contact_id`. But this is all academic talk. The real solution is a sane data model.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter why do you keep commenting that using json/jsonb for foreign keys is "insane"?  it seems postgres either does JSON/JSONB or it doesn't, and if it can't use a foreign key in JSON/JSONB then it's a shortcoming of postgres.  I am just ramping up on it, maybe I'm asking too much of it...?

Answer (score 20):

#### Proof of concept

Your "crude way" doesn't actually work. Here is another crude way that does:

```
SELECT *
FROM  auth_contacts a
    , jsonb_to_recordset(a.contacts->'contact') AS c(contact_id text)
JOIN  discussion d USING (contact_id);
```

As has been commented, you can also formulate a join condition with the [contains operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```
SELECT *
FROM   auth_contacts a
JOIN   discussion d ON a.contacts->'contact'
                    @> json_build_array(json_build_object('contact_id', d.contact_id))::jsonb
```

But rather use JSON creation functions than string concatenation. Looks cumbersome but will actually be very fast if supported with a *functional jsonb_path_ops GIN* index:

```
CREATE INDEX auth_contacts_contacts_gin_idx ON auth_contacts
USING  gin ((contacts->'contact') jsonb_path_ops);
```

Details:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)
- [Postgres 9.4 jsonb array as table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827578/postgres-9-4-jsonb-array-as-table/30829650#30829650)

#### Proper solution

This is all fascinating to play with, but the problem here is the relational model. Your claim:

> hence making it non JSONB type is not appropriate according as it
> would double or triple the amount of records.

is **the opposite of what's right**. It's **nonsense** to wrap IDs you need for joining tables into a JSON document type. Normalize your table with a many-to-many relationship and implement all IDs you are working with inside the DB as separate columns with appropriate data type. Basics:

- [How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb/26704636#26704636)
- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: @PrachiTripathi: `jsonb_object_keys()` makes sense for that. But you also have a plain syntax error. `c.contacts` should probably be `a.contacts`.

Comment: Apologies-my crude way works where I store it as follows: {"3-1LS-86": "type_a", "3-1IC-1432": "type_b"} and not as array,hence the  subquery of keys works. Abt the proper solution agreed it shud be relational but consider auth_contacts table : number of users we are looking at could be a hundred thousand (100000+ ) and per user authorized contacts could be on an average 6000 and some thousand of users have 60k+ authorized contacts. Now, rows in auth contacts would be 500million+ records which is why i felt a join on this with timeline having 1million records would kill the system,wouldnt it?

Comment: Also its a one to many relationship between user and authhorized contacts and not many to many (Userid, auth_contacts)

Comment: Looks like an n:m relationship between `auth_contacts` and `discussion`. But I don't know the details. If you expect that many rows, be sure not use integer (or bigint if you must) for ID columns and not string types.

Comment: Yes using ID is ok. But I am still wondering when postgres JSONB when searched online shows it is faster than MongoDB but the join as given in example takes 28 seconds for a user who has 70k + contacts

Comment: @Prachi: There are *certainly* ways to make this faster, even with your subptimal current db design. Best start a *new question* so not to overload this one. Provide essential information: exact table definition, which columns you need to return (you don't need `SELECT *`, do you?), which indexes you created and the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` - best post to explain.depesz.com and post the link. Consider instructions in the **[tag info to `[postgresql-performance]`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info)**. You can always link to this question for context.