# Avoid anonymous fields in JSON built from table rows

Tags: json, postgresql, field, anonymous

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  item_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  item_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  mal_item_name VARCHAR(255),
  active CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  data_needed CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  parent_id INTEGER);
```

The query:

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t))) 
from (select item_id as id, 
             item_name as text, 
             parent_id as parent,
             (mal_item_name,data_needed) as data 
      from test) t
```

produces result:

```
[{"id":1,"text":"Materials","parent":0, "data": {"f1":null,"f2":"N"}},
 {"id":2,"text":"Bricks","parent":1, "data":{"f1":null,"f2":"N"}},
 {"id":3,"text":"Class(high)","parent":2, "data":{"f1":null,"f2":"Y"}},
 {"id":4,"text":"Class(low)","parent":2, "data":{"f1":null,"f2":"Y"}}]
```

The original field names `mal_item_name`  and `data_needed` are replaced with `f1` and `f2`.
How can I get a JSON with field names itself? Documentation says by creating a type for these two fields. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Your version of Postgres would be essential to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`json_build_object()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) in Postgres **9.4** or later:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(t) AS js
FROM  (SELECT item_id   AS id
            , item_name AS text
            , parent_id AS parent
            , json_build_object('mal_item_name', mal_item_name
                               ,'data_needed', data_needed) AS data
       FROM test) t;
```

And use [`json_agg(...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) instead of `array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(...)))`.

For Postgres **9.3**:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(t) AS js
FROM  (SELECT item_id   AS id
            , item_name AS text
            , parent_id AS parent
            , (SELECT t FROM (SELECT mal_item_name, data_needed) 
                                AS t(mal_item_name, data_needed)) AS data
       FROM test) t;
```

Details:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)
- [Using row_to_json() with nested joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227142/postgresql-9-2-row-to-json-with-nested-joins)
- [PostgreSQL : select columns inside json_agg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69658/3684)

Comment: I am using Postgres 9.3

Comment: Added a solution for 9.3. Be sure to follow the links for detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I looked for. Will go through details link for sure.