# How can I get a hierarchial json from the same table in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

```
{
      object_id: 1,
      text: [
         en: { name: xxx, desc: xxx },
         pl: { name: xxx, desc: xxx }
      ]
   }
```

my table looks like this

```
id, name, desc, object_id, language
```

and some of the data looks like this:

```
1, xxx, xxx, 1, en
2, xxx, xxx, 2, pl
3, xxx, xxx, 1, pl 
4, xxx, xxx, 2, de
```

I want to aggregate the name and desc of the those who have the same object_id in the text field in the response

I am working on postgres 9.3

Answer (score 1):

The question contains inaccuracies: the expected result is not a valid json and the table is not properly defined.

Assume that the table definition is:

```
create table the_table
(
  id integer,
  some_name text,   -- do not use 'name' for column name
  descr text,       -- 'desc' is invalid column name
  object_id integer,
  lang text         -- do not use 'language' for column name
)
```

The query:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object('object_id', object_id, 'text', js))
from (
    select object_id, json_agg(js) js
    from (
        select 
            object_id, 
            lang, 
            json_build_object(
                lang, 
                json_object(array['name', some_name, 'desc', descr])
            ) js
        from the_table
        order by lang
        ) alias
    group by 1
    ) alias
```

produces [this valid json](http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate/2798a3).

**Postgres 9.3 solution**

Postgres 9.4 came with a powerful function `json_build_object(variadic "any")`. 
It is impossible to substitute it with your own function because plpgsql does not allow `variadic "any"` as an argument.
For the purposes of Postgres 9.3 we will use three functions that operate on text type (rather than on json), and the simplest aggregate function `string_agg` 
(this solution is sufficient, although more elegant would be to define our own aggregate function).

```
create function js_clear(t text)
returns text language sql as $$
    select replace(replace(replace(replace(t,'"[','['), '"{','{'), '}"','}'), ']"',']');
$$;

create function js_array(t text)
returns text language sql as $$
    select format('[%s]', js_clear(t));
$$;

create function js_object(variadic args text[])
returns text language plpgsql as $$
declare
    res text = '';
begin
    for i in 1 .. array_length(args, 1) by 2 loop
        res:= format('%s"%s" : "%s", ', res, args[i], args[i+1]);
    end loop;
    return format('{%s}', rtrim(js_clear(res), ', '));
end $$;
```

The query in 9.3 version:

```
select js_array(string_agg(js_object('object_id', object_id::text, 'text', js), ', '))
from (
    select object_id, js_array(string_agg(js, ', ')) js
    from (
        select 
            object_id, 
            lang, 
            js_object(
                lang, 
                js_object('name', some_name, 'desc', descr)
            ) js
        from the_table
        order by lang
        ) alias
    group by 1
    ) alias
```

Comment: is json_object is from postgres 9.4? How can I do this with postgres 9.3?

Comment: `json_build_object()` and `json_object()` were introduced in 9.4. It is possible to substitute them in 9.3 but that is a bit complicated.

Comment: ohhh...could you please point me to some reference on that? that would be very helpful

Comment: I must leave now but I'll be back!

Comment: @kiln the array of objects in the `"text"` fields seems a little over-structured; with `json_object_agg()` that could be `"text":{"de":{...},"pl":{...}}` (but that's also 9.4+ feature).

Comment: @user494461 I'm afraid in 9.3, you have to build your `json` objects manually, like `concat('{"name":', to_json(some_name), ',"desc":', to_json(descr), '}')::json` (or use `row_to_json()` for that, but you'll need [aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227142/postgresql-9-2-row-to-json-with-nested-joins))

Comment: @pozs - Right, json might be a bit simpler, but luckily this structure can be easily implemented in 9.3.