# What is a row constructor used for?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, row

In PostgreSQL, what is the `ROW()` function used for?

Specifically what is the difference between

```
SELECT ROW(t.f1, t.f2, 42) FROM t;
```

where `f1` is of type `int`, `f2` is of type `text`

and

```
CREATE TYPE myrowtype AS (f1 int, f2 text, f3 numeric);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are confusing levels of abstraction. As other answers already point out, `CREATE TYPE` only registers a (composite / row) type in the system. While a `ROW` constructor actually returns a row.

A row type created with the `ROW` constructor does not preserve column names, which becomes evident when you try to convert the row to JSON.

While being at it, `ROW` is just a ***noise word*** most of the time. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)

> The key word `ROW` is optional when there is more than one expression in the list.

Demo:

```sql
SELECT t                              AS r1, row_to_json(t)                           AS j1
     , ROW(1, 'x', numeric '42.1')    AS r2, row_to_json(ROW(1, 'x', numeric '42.1')) AS j2
     ,    (1, 'x', numeric '42.1')    AS r3, row_to_json(   (1, 'x', numeric '42.1')) AS j3
     ,    (1, 'x', '42.1')::myrowtype AS r4, row_to_json((1, 'x', '42.1')::myrowtype) AS j4
FROM  (SELECT 1, 'x', numeric '42.1') t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=37e82cba88dc7a62538ab096acd1060d)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/af436/1)</sub>

`r1` and `j1` preserve original column names.
`r2` and `j2` do not.
`r3` and `j3` are the same; to demonstrate how `ROW` is just noise.
`r4` and `j4` carry the column names of the registered type.

You can cast the row (record) to a registered row type if *number* and *data types* of the elements match the row type - *names* of input fields are ignored.

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 3):

Row constructors can be used to build composite values to be stored in a composite-type table column, or to be passed to a function that accepts a composite parameter. 
Also, it is possible to compare two row values or test a row with IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

[4.2.13. Row Constructors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html)

Example:

```
CREATE TYPE myrowtype AS (f1 int, f2 text, f3 numeric);
CREATE TABLE mytable (ct myrowtype);
INSERT INTO mytable(ct) VALUES (CAST(ROW(11,'this is a test',2.5) AS myrowtype));
```

Answer (score 3):

You're asking about the difference between a *value* and a *type*.

It's about the same difference than between an object and a class in an OO language.

In the first case you're building a value which could be used in comparisons, in row writing, or to be passed to functions accepting composite parameters.

In the second case you're defining a type that can be used for example in a function or table definition.

Comment: At its **_Ingres_** heart, PG is OO. I think that's why we've been able to enjoy advanced SQL language features from early on (inherits, array, hstore, etc..), with JSON giving us a complete round trip of unpivot-->(re)pivot. And the more I use PG the more I find I'm doing functional programming (SQL generally, but PG especially).

Answer (score 2):

`ROW(...)` is not a function. It's SQL syntax, more like the `ARRAY[...]` constructor than like a function.

The `ROW` constructor is primarily used to form anonymous records. This can be useful when you need to keep a collection of fields together, but they don't correspond to an existing table type or composite data type.

These two are equivalent in PostgreSQL:

```
test=> SELECT t FROM (SELECT 1, 'x', NUMERIC '42.1') AS t;
     t      
------------
 (1,x,42.1)
(1 row)

test=> SELECT ROW(1, 'x', NUMERIC '42.1');
    row     
------------
 (1,x,42.1)
(1 row)
```

in that both create an anonymous record:

```
test=> SELECT pg_typeof(t) FROM (SELECT 1, 'x', NUMERIC '42.1') AS t;
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 record
(1 row)

test=> SELECT pg_typeof(ROW(1, 'x', NUMERIC '42.1'));
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 record
(1 row)
```

The records created by `ROW` can correspond to existing types, for when you're passing composite types to a function, e.g given:

```
CREATE TYPE myrowtype AS (f1 int, f2 text, f3 numeric);
```

you can create a `myrowtype` with:

```
test=> SELECT CAST(ROW(1, 'x', '42.1') AS myrowtype);
    row     
------------
 (1,x,42.1)
(1 row)
```

Comment: Not *completely* equivalent, like you worked out yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13227451/939860

Comment: Could we reference a field from ROW(...) without CREATE TYPE ?

Comment: @Charlie木匠 fields in ROW() seem to have names like f1, f2 etc.
`select (row(1,2,3)).f2` returns "2". But I still can't find a way to name fields without creating a named type.

Comment: @codesnik In some contexts you can use a scalar subquery like `(SELECT 1 AS f1, 'foo' AS f2)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've exited database field for 5 years.  :)

Comment: @charlie-木匠 that's the holy grail, to dynamically cast w/out creating a type.

Interestingly, TEMP TABLES will serve in the stead of a permanent type. 

A quick anonymous proc w/ a LOOP to create a temp table "tmp_new_type" is feasible (my project du jour AAMOF) and so long as the row-types are compatible, then we can cast between types like this:

`SELECT ( (  ROW(   (r).* ) )::tmp_new_type ).*   `

A potential downside to a temp table is stability: I've observed server ab-ends in older PG versions when doing this, dropping a temp table w/out a cascade arg.

Comment: @codesnik There is a way to do this w/ intervening JSON functions, but you'll have to hard-code column names as a simple alias list when casting (similar to the CROSSTAB() function). Otherwise the pre-defined type can be a temp table (see prev. comment).

Answer (score 0):

A quick aside, we can cast to-and-fro from one table type to another, with restrictions:

```
   /** create a TYPE **/
   CREATE  TYPE tyNewNames AS ( a int, b int , c int )  ;

    SELECT
     /** note: order, type & # of columns must match exactly**/
       ROW((rec).*)::tyNewNames    AS "rec newNames" -- f1,f2,f3 --> a,b,c
    , (ROW((rec).*)::tyNewNames).* -- expand the new names
    ,'<new vs. old>' AS "<new vs. old>"
    ,*
    FROM
        (
          SELECT
            /** inspecting rec: PG assigned stand-in names f1, f2, f3, etc... **/
             rec     /* a record*/ 
            ,(rec).* -- expanded fields f1, f2, f3
            FROM (
                    SELECT ( 1, 2, 3 ) AS rec -- an anon type record
                  ) cte0
        )cte1
    ;

+---------+-+-+-++------------+--------+--+--+--+
|rec                          |rec              |
|newnames |a|b|c|<new vs. old>|oldnames|f1|f2|f3|
+---------+-+-+-++------------+--------+--+--+--+
|(1,2,3)  |1|2|3|<new vs. old>|(1,2,3) |1 |2 |3 |
+---------+-+-+-++------------+--------+--+--+--+
```

A compressed example of this code might look like this:

```
SELECT ( (  ROW(   (rec).* ) )::tyNewNames ).* ;
```

db fiddle(uk)
https://dbfiddle.uk/dlTxd8Y3

However as Erwin points out, with the exception of a few cases, ROW() is a noise word. It's also possible to simply recast the record on-the-fly with the new field names, and without the nested CTE's:

```
 /** create a TYPE **/
CREATE  TYPE tyNewNames AS ( a int, b int , c int )  ;
 
SELECT ( 1, 2, 3 )    -- an anon type record
,  (ROW( 1, 2, 3 )).* -- anon field names f1, f2, f3 with  ROW() wrapper
,  (   ( 1, 2, 3 )).* -- anon field names f1, f2, f3 w/out ROW() wrapper        

/** cast to new names OTF , f1,f2,f3 --> a,b,c **/
, ( ROW( 1 ,2 ,3 )::tyNewNames ).* --    row() wrapper
, (    ( 1 ,2 ,3 )::tyNewNames ).* -- no row() wrapper
;
+-------+--+--+--+---+--+---+--+-+-+--+-+-+
|row    |f1|f2|f3| f1|f2|f3 | a|b|c| a|b|c|
+-------+--+--+--+---+--+---+--+-+-+--+-+-+
|(1,2,3)|1 |2 |3 |  1| 2| 3 | 1|2|3| 1|2|3|
+-------+--+--+--+---+--+---+--+-+-+--+-+-+
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/OPJcuzs7