# Grouping records on consecutive dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, gaps-and-islands

If I have following table in Postgres:

**order_dtls**

```
Order_id    Order_date  Customer_name
-------------------------------------
1           11/09/17    Xyz
2           15/09/17    Lmn
3           12/09/17    Xyz
4           18/09/17    Abc
5           15/09/17    Xyz
6           25/09/17    Lmn
7           19/09/17    Abc
```

I want to retrieve such customer who has placed orders on 2 consecutive days.
In above case `Xyz` and `Abc` customers should be returned by query as result.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: So what is your actual problem? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am using Postgresql, my problem is how to apply group by clause on 2 dates which are consicutive

Comment: Your last comment made the requirement less clear - it might help if you could expand your sample data to illustrate what you mean by group by and  what happens if a customer has events on 3,4(etc) consecutive days.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Use an [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join followed by [`DISTINCT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) or `GROUP BY`, should be among the fastest.

**Postgres** syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_name
FROM   order_dtls o
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELEST 1 FROM order_dtls
   WHERE  customer_name = o.customer_name
   AND    order_date = o.order_date + 1  -- simple syntax for data type "date" in Postgres!
   );
```

If the table is big, be sure to have an index on `(customer_name, order_date)` to make it fast - index items in this order.

To clarify, since Oto happened to post [*almost* the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46365258/939860) a bit faster:

[`DISTINCT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) is an SQL construct, a syntax element, not a function. Do ***not*** use parentheses like <strike>`DISTINCT (customer_name)`</strike>. Would be short for `DISTINCT ROW(customer_name)` - a row constructor unrelated to `DISTINCT` - and just noise for the simple case with a single expression, because Postgres removes the pointless row wrapper for a single element automatically. But if you wrap more than one expression like that, you get an actual row type - an anonymous record actually, since no row type is given. Most certainly not what you want.

- [What is a row constructor used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164926/what-is-a-row-constructor-used-for/32173749#32173749)

Also, don't confuse `DISTINCT` with `DISTINCT ON (expr, ...)`. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT A.customer_name
    FROM order_dtls A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT customer_name, order_date FROM order_dtls) as B
    ON(A.customer_name = B.customer_name and Datediff(B.Order_date, A.Order_date) =1)
    group by A.customer_name
```

Comment: Datediff(B.order,A.order) should probably be Datediff(B.order_date,A.order_date)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would think of it doing it would be to join the table the date part with itselft on the next date and joining it with the Customer_name too.
This way you can ensure that the same customer_name done an order on 2 consecutive days.

For MySQL:

```
SELECT distinct *
FROM order_dtls t1
    INNER JOIN order_dtls t2 on
            t1.Order_date = DATE_ADD(t2.Order_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) and
            t1.Customer_name = t2.Customer_name
```

The result you should also select it with the Distinct keyword to ensure the same customer is not displayed more than 1 time.

Comment: Neither mysql nor postgresql have a dateadd function. Mysql syntax would be DATE_ADD(t2.Order_date, interval 1 day) in which case solution produces expected result.

Comment: You are totally right. I will modify the answer to include MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
SELECT `order_dtls`.*
FROM `order_dtls`
INNER JOIN `order_dtls` AS mirror
ON `order_dtls`.`Order_id` <> `mirror`.`Order_id`
AND `order_dtls`.`Customer_name` = `mirror`.`Customer_name`
AND DATEDIFF(`order_dtls`.`Order_date`, `mirror`.`Order_date`) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For postgresql:

```
select distinct(Customer_name) from your_table
where exists 
    (select 1 from your_table t1 
    where 
    Customer_name = your_table.Customer_name and Order_date = your_table.Order_date+1 )
```

Same for MySQL, just instead of `your_table.Order_date+1` use:  `DATE_ADD(your_table.Order_date , INTERVAL 1 DAY)`