# Converting select statement directly into json array

Tags: postgresql

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439256/how-do-i-retrieve-data-from-multiple-related-tables-in-postgres), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006291/postgresql-return-result-set-as-json-array/24006432) I have figured out that if I want to aggregate a set of related rows into an array of objects I have to use this syntax:

```
(select to_json(C) from ( /* subquery */ ) C)
```

So, if I have three tables: `user`, `creature` and their junction table `user_creature`:

[image]

And I want to retrieve each user, and each creature that belongs to this user, I would have to do something like this:

```
select to_json(T)
from (
         select "user".id        as user_id,
                (select to_json(C) -- !!! There it is
                 from (
                          select name, height
                          from creature
                                   inner join "user_creature" uc on creature.id = "uc".creature_id
                                   inner join "user" u on "uc".user_id = u.id
                          where u.id = user_id
                      ) C)       as "creatures" -- !!! There it is
         from "user"
     ) T;
```

This query successfully retrieves a list of users and their related creatures:

[image]

Is there a way to drop `select` and `from` keywords from the query, so that I can write my query like this:

```
select to_json(T)
from (
         select "user".id        as user_id,
                to_json( -- !!! Calling to_json directly on select statement
                      select name, height
                      from creature
                               inner join "user_creature" uc on creature.id = "uc".creature_id
                               inner join "user" u on "uc".user_id = u.id
                      where u.id = user_id
                  )  as "creatures"
         from "user"
     ) T;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post some sample data and JSON output you want by editing your question

Comment: Why do you use a junction table? Your query suggests that each user can have only a single creature - it would fail with multiple creatures. Or did you plan to use `json_agg`?

Comment: It's just an example for testing. I use it to solve a problem where I actually need a junction table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use a subquery as the argument to `to_json`, but not practical:

- You need to wrap the subquery in a grouping parenthesis: `to_json( (SELECT … FROM …) )`
- The subquery must return exactly one row (but that's normal)
- The subquery must return exactly one column. This is a bit harder - you *can* return a record, but if you build it dynamically (e.g. from a selection of columns, you can hardly control the field names)

(See a [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=75283211ebeb82971176ceac88df99eb)).

Instead, use `json_build_object` if you want to write a single `SELECT` query only:

```
SELECT json_build_object(
  'user_id', u.id,
  'creatures', (
    SELECT json_build_object(
      'name', c.name,
      'height', c.height
    )
    FROM creature c
    INNER JOIN "user_creature" uc ON c.id = uc.creature_id
    WHERE uc.user_id = u.id
  )
)
FROM "user" u;
```

And, if you want to be able to retrieve multiple rows use `SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(…)) FROM …` or `ARRAY(SELECT json_build_object(…) FROM …)`:

```
SELECT json_build_object(
  'user_id', u.id,
  'creatures', (
    SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
      'name', c.name,
      'height', c.height
    ))
    FROM creature c
    INNER JOIN "user_creature" uc ON c.id = uc.creature_id
    WHERE uc.user_id = u.id
  )
)
FROM "user" u;
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I have more than one row returned? If I run this query against a user table that has multiple creatures, then I get an error saying: "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Comment: @RuslanPlastun That's what I asked in the question comments :-) I had assumed you weren't getting multiple rows, and got the expected JSON result with a single creature object. If what you actually want to get is an array of creature objects, use `SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(…)) FROM …` or `ARRAY(SELECT json_build_object(…) FROM …)`.