# Duplicate JSON element in row_to_json() with self-join

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, sjson

This is a follow-up to this excellent Q&A: [13227142](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13227451/2878556).

I almost have to do the same thing (with the constraint of PostgreSQL 9.2) but I'm using only one table. Therefore the query uses a self-join (in order to produce the correct JSON format) which results in a duplicate *id* field. How can I avoid this?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE books
(
  id serial primary key,
  isbn text,
  author text,
  title text,
  edition text,
  teaser text
);

SELECT row_to_json(row)
FROM
(
  SELECT id AS bookid,
  author,
  cover
  FROM books
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT id, title, edition, teaser
    FROM books
  ) cover(id, title, edition, teaser)
  USING (id)
) row;
```

Result:

```
{
  "bookid": 1,
  "author": "Bjarne Stroustrup",
  "cover": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Design and Evolution of C++",
    "edition": "1st edition",
    "teaser": "This book focuses on the principles, processes and decisions made during the development of the C++ programming language"
  }
}
```

I want to get rid of "id" in "cover".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a tricky task. As far as I can see it's impossible to achieve with a simple query.
One solution is to use a predefined data type:

```
CREATE TYPE bookcovertype AS (title text, edition text, teaser text);

SELECT row_to_json(row)
FROM
(
  SELECT books.id AS bookid, books.author, 
    row_to_json(row(books.title, books.edition, books.teaser)::bookcovertype) as cover
  FROM books
) row;
```

Comment: This is solution is compatible to Postgres 9.2, thanks

Comment: I looked at the query again and realized that `JOIN` is absolutely unnecessary here. I updated the query.

Answer (score 1):

you need id to join, so without id you can't make such short query. You need to struct it. Smth like:

```
select row_to_json(row,true)
FROM
(
with a as (select id,isbn,author,row_to_json((title,edition,teaser)) r from books
)
select a.id AS bookid,a.author, concat('{"title":',r->'f1',',"edition":',r->'f2',',"teaser":',r->'f3','}')::json as cover
  from a
) row;
                      row_to_json
--------------------------------------------------------
 {"bookid":1,                                          +
  "author":"\"b\"",                                    +
  "cover":{"title":"c","edition":"d","teaser":"\"b\""}}
(1 row)
```

**Also without join you use twice as less resources**

Comment: It will fail if value contains special characters, like `"`

Comment: added escaping to avoid it

Comment: Unfortunately, `to_json()` is available only as of version 9.3

Comment: Anyway, it's possible to implement your own text-escaping function. So it's a possible solution.

Comment: used row_to_json for escaping

Comment: Wow, that was smart!

Comment: Are the JSON operators `->`supported in 9.2? I only see them in the 9.3 docs. `ERROR:  operator does not exist: json -> unknown`

Comment: Thanks anyway, I can switch to this solution if we upgrade to 9.3... (ever *sigh*)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness I've stumbled upon another answer myself: The additional fields can be eliminated by string functions. However, I prefer **AlexM**'s anwer because it will be faster and is still compatible with PostgreSQL 9.2.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
  (
      SELECT row_to_json(row)
      FROM
      (
        SELECT id AS bookid,
        author,
        cover
        FROM books
        INNER JOIN 
        (
          SELECT id, title, edition, teaser
          FROM books
        ) cover(id, title, edition, teaser)
        USING (id)
      ) row
  )::text,
  '"id":\d+,',
  '')
```